# Kafka PartitionLeaderEopch, epoch < lastEpoch

Tags: apache-kafka

In a mostly default cluster of 3 brokers, I am getting spammed with these logs:

```
Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. This
implies messages have arrived out of order. New: {epoch:4, offset:64609385},
Current: {epoch:176, offset63321945} for Partition: mytopic-46 
(kafka.server.epoch.LeaderEpochFileCache)
```

Google is not turning up particularly useful results. What is the problem here? Or where could I continue (or rather start) my search for the actual problem and solution?

EDIT: it did not only happen once per partition, but over and over again over a long time. I cannot check now, but I believe it is an older Kafka version (around 1.0'ish).

Comment: You should see this exactly one time for each partition and then it should stop. Is this consistent with what you see? 
It indicates that the leader epoch in ZK got out of sync with the version stored in local file. The controller should automatically resolve it.

If this is not the case, can you share your Kafka version?

Comment: Edited the question, @GwenShapira.